# How to Tune Delete operation over the DB Link

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-delete

I am working on Oracle 12c database and I am performing Delete operation between source database to target database over db_link. The delete operation is taking huge time and I have to tune it.

I have already tried Driving site hint on target but still its taking lot of time in execution. The source table has like 1.2 million records and target table have records like 38 million. Report_id and Id columns are respective PK's of there tables.

```
Delete from PRIMARY_TABLE WHERE REPORT_ID IN (SELECT ID FROM PROCESS_DATA@PVA_TO_SRC WHERE TYPE='E');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a batch job/one off job then i suggest you bring the the 1.2 million rows table to the same database as the target as the first step.

Eg:
CREATE TABLE TEMP_DELETE AS
SELECT ID 
  FROM PROCESS_DATA@PVA_TO_SRC 
  WHERE TYPE='E'

Followed by gathering statistics on the newly created table. After that the delete should work out better.

Also a 38 million row table must have been partitioned on a field?. if there is any way you can use the partition key in destination table and link it with the records in TEMP_DELETE it would make the delete better.

Also if you got indexes on 38 million table. Drop those indexes, perform the delete and then recreate the index

Answer (score 0):

Create a `materialized view` for

```
SELECT ID FROM PROCESS_DATA@PVA_TO_SRC WHERE TYPE='E';
```

Whenever you want to delete the data just refresh it. Also you can use index on it.

Cheers!!